# How do I compare mathematical operations between values in two columns of an R data frame based on their position?

Tags: r, loops, foreach, dataframe

any help please in fact  I have this data frame named data:

```
            ID  nom  pd1  pd2 pd3
            10  A10  A10C BC1 tt12
            5   A10C BCN  hJK  LMK
            7   BC1  hmn  ...  ...
```

if we remark , we have `data[,2][2]==data[,3][1]` in this case I hope to transform

```
data[,2][1]<-data[,1][2] .
```

I hope to do  this for columns: pd1,pd2...
My final data wil be like this

```
ID  nom  pd1  pd2 pd3
10  A10  5    7   tt12
5   A10C BCN  hJK  LMK
7   BC1  hmn  ...  ...
```

Comment: Instead of `...`, please show a proper example

Comment: @akrun,thanks fo reply , it is an example , my objectif is to change products names(pd1,pd2...) with their ID , any help

Comment: i hope to transform the first table into the second table :  for the column named pd1, ihave tried this :                   
                      for (i in 1:nrow(data))
{
  for(j in 1:nrow(data))
    {
    
  if  data[,3][i,j]==data[,2][i,j]
  
    data[,3][i,j]=data[1,][i,j]
  }
}                          but it does not works, and i hope to do this operation for all columns, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We get the index of column names that start with 'pd' (`nm1`).  Loop through those columns with `lapply`, `match` each column with the 'nom' column to get the row index.  Using `ifelse`, we change the `NA` elements with the column values and the rest of the values from the 'ID' column.

```
nm1 <- grep('^pd', names(df1))
df1[nm1] <- lapply(df1[nm1], function(x) {
      i1 <- match(x, df1[['nom']])
       ifelse(is.na(i1), x, df1$ID[i1])})
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(10L, 5L, 7L), nom = c("A10", 
 "A10C", "BC1"
), pd1 = c("A10C", "BCN", "hmn"), pd2 = c("BC1", "hJK", "hJj"
), pd3 = c("tt12", "LMK", "jkl")), .Names = c("ID", "nom", "pd1", 
"pd2", "pd3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if your workaround is OK? you could replace specified parameters like

```
data[which(data$pd1=="A10C"), "pd1"] = 5
```

an so on

Comment: @akrun, your first solution it works , but i can not used your second data<-.... because i have a  big data. thanks

Comment: Miroslav:thanks but in my case i must change all columns not only one